# Using Module.Exports in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to access the value from an array trough module.exports, as you can see in the attached code I have to files: inputs.js and files.js and I need to read the value 'file' from the function askingForImputs.

So far I have tried creating an object from the inputs file. but I either get undefined or any other error. This is what I have so far.

**inputs.js**

```
module.exports = {
  askingInputs: () => {
    const questions = [
      {
        name: "file",
        type: "input",
        message: "Enter file to be analized:",
        validate: function (value) {
          if (value.length) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return "File doesn't exist";
          }
        },
      },
    ];
    return inquirer.prompt(questions);
  },
};
```

**file.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const inputs = require("/inputs");

module.exports = {
  readingFile: () => {

// here I need to access the value of file from inputs.

    fs.readFile("./files/Example.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: In the `file.js` you obviously need to call the `askingInputs` function. So try `inputs.askingInputs().then(function(answers){ console.log(answers); })` Now you probably want to check the first answer `answers[0]`, one of the object's properties  should be your file.

Comment: Hello Molda, thank you for the answer. I tried your solution but I'm receiving an undefined response. For some reason the value of file is not being returned. But once again thank you.

Comment: Should `require("/inputs")` be `require("inputs")`?